# Unable to put a regular expression for a particular String

Tags: python, regex

In my Python code, I have a string that starts with Jira id like:-

```
<Jira Id in upper case>: <Commit Message>
```

for example, it appears like this:-

```
FD-0827: This is a test commit only
```

Here, '**FD**' followed by a hyphen is important and remains static followed by dynamic numbers. I want the colon as a delimiter as well followed by any message.

So far I tried below code format for regex but have not been able to put some conditions around it:-
`JIRA_REGEX = "(\w+)-(\d+)"` -> **works but allows the lower case of FD as well and no check of colon**
`JIRA_REGEX = "^[A-Z]-(\d+)"` -> **does not work at all**

In any case, it should look for the colon as well.

How can I put regex that strictly looks for

```
<Jira Id in upper case>: <Commit Message>
```

Comment: `JIRA_REGEX = "^([A-Z]+)-(\d+):\s*(.*)"`

Comment: Maybe `JIRA_REGEX = "^([A-Z]+)-(\d+):\s*([^\n]*)"` if the pattern is supposed to be applied on a file, it assures to handle the new line character.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want sometthing like this ?

```
import re

JIRA_REGEX = "^[A-Z]{2}-\d+:"

string = "FD-0827: This is a test commit only"

match = re.match(JIRA_REGEX, string)
if match:
    print("Valid Jira ID and commit message format")
else:
    print("Invalid Jira ID and commit message format")
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex would also work:
`[A-Z]{2}-\d+:(?:\s\w+)+`

- `[A-Z]{2}` - matches two upper case characters
- `-` - matches the hyphen
- `\d+`- few digits of the Jira id
- `:` - matches the colon
- `(?:\s\w+)+` - few space separated words

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KGFFv2/1)